# How do I install a jQuery plugin on Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, plugins, github

I'm trying to install a jQuery plugin, https://github.com/motyar/firefly to my site. (instructions: http://www.backslash.gr/content/blog/webdevelopment/10-jquery-firefly-plugin)

I followed the tutorial and it didn't work. Is there a special process for getting jQuery plugins onto rails? I tried cloning the repository but it didn't work. I also ran "rails plugin new 'git@github.com:motyar/firefly.git'" and it gives me this:

```
Usage:
  rails plugin new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some plugin template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the plugin with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the plugin with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--dummy-path=DUMMY_PATH]                          # Create dummy application at given path
                                                         # Default: test/dummy
      [--full], [--no-full]                              # Generate a rails engine with bundled Rails application for testing
      [--mountable], [--no-mountable]                    # Generate mountable isolated application
      [--skip-gemspec], [--no-skip-gemspec]              # Skip gemspec file
      [--skip-gemfile-entry], [--no-skip-gemfile-entry]  # If creating plugin in application's directory skip adding entry to Gemfile

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]  # Show this help message and quit

Description:
    The 'rails plugin new' command creates a skeleton for developing any
    kind of Rails extension with ability to run tests using dummy Rails
    application.

Example:
    rails plugin new ~/Code/Ruby/blog

    This generates a skeletal Rails plugin in ~/Code/Ruby/blog.
    See the README in the newly created plugin to get going.
```

I also tried running 'gem 'firefly' :git => 'https://github.com/motyar/firefly' and that didn't work either.

What do? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

No.

The command `rails plugin new` is used to create new plugin for Rails' applications. And firefly isn't a gem, then you cant install it by `gem install` command.

To add this `jquery` plugin to your app, add [this file](https://github.com/motyar/firefly/blob/master/jquery.firefly-0.4.js) to `vendor/assets/javascripts` or `app/assets/javascripts` folder.

And remember to require it on `application.js`.